# Xlib keyboard polling

Tags: linux, opengl, input, xlib

I'm working on a multi-platform OpenGL application, for which I'm using Xlib under Linux. I understand that Xlib input handling is strongly event-based, but my program already does its own event handling, and I'd much rather be able to poll the xserver for any keys which were pressed or raised under the active window since the last poll.

If I have to use event-based input handling under X, I'd have to do the same for other platforms, while rewriting a lot of code, since the event methods are so different from one platform to another. Polling would really simplify things for me, but I'm afraid there would be substantial overhead with something like this, and I haven't even been able to get information on how it should be done. I've thought of checking the /dev/input/eventX node directly, but that would probably make things more complicated, rather than simplifying.

What I really want to know is how to efficiently poll the keyboard state on Linux systems. Am I wasting my time with Xlib, and should I consider other techniques or libraries?

Comment: "the event methods are so different from one platform to another" ... What? I'm *pretty* sure they're all based on "key goes down" and "key comes up"...

Comment: I would suggest you investigate SDL or SFML to abstract away this sort of thing.

Comment: You can't even poll /dev/input/eventX, I mean the name itself already suggests it's event based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To efficiently poll, I usually use `select` (on `ConnectionNumber`), to wait until something happens on the connection to X and then while `XPending` I use `XNextEvent` to grab stuff.  Do not call `XNextEvent` unless `XPending` or else it will block.

Conveniently, `select` provides a timeout mechanism, so you can also stop waiting periodically to do something else (like drawing) quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Polling means, that you'll have some loop somewhere in your program. Use XPending to check if there's something new from the server (that's your poll), then use XNextEvent to read it.